# Propagation of NS records specified in Cloudflare

Tags: dns, nameserver, cloudflare

I own a domain, `example.com`.
At my registrar, the NS records of my domain point to `xxx.ns.cloudflare.com` and `yyy.ns.cloudflare.com`.
Now I would suppose that when I add NS records on Cloudflare (in the DNS settings on `cloudflare.com`) pointing to `ns1.myhostingprovider.com`, `ns2.myhostingprovider.com`, ... (the name servers for my hosting provider 8-)) that I'd be able to resolve `example.com` to `A.B.C.D`, the IP of the server on which my hosting provider has my site for `example.com` hosted.

When taking out the Cloudflare "middle man", this works flawlessly.
However, the configuration including Cloudflare does not work.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Or if it were intentional, could someone explain me the use of NS records in the Cloudflare settings it they can't be used in this way?

(I know I wouldn't be able to use Cloudflare's caching, protection, etc. in this configuration. This is not the objective... =))

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using CloudFlare correctly. At your domain registrar, you should be using CloudFlare's nameservers (e.g., `nsname.cloudflare.com`), which would then provide the DNS records, such as the `A` record that points to the IP address of your server. If you want to use _custom nameservers_, then you'd have to upgrade to their Business plan. See the following for more:  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202320534-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-without-changing-my-nameservers-to-CloudFlare-

Comment: I have several domains. I use Cloudflare on them all, but don't have the CDN and performance features turned on for each of them. So I do know how Cloudflare works :) At my registrar, I am using Cloudflare's nameservers. For the moment, all my domains are setup at Cloudflare with the correct A records. But I am wondering if there is no possibility to exchange the A record (on domains that do not use the CDN ...) with a NS record. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible on domains where Cloudflare is only acting as the DNS provider.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking then, because you stated that you're pointing back to your own nameservers and that  this doesn't work...what is your objective: to use custom nameservers, provide redundancy, or something else...?

Comment: I see you edited your comment after mine... `I am wondering if there is no possibility to exchange the A record (on domains that do not use the CDN ...) with a NS record` <- In order to provide DNS, whether you use CloudFlare as a proxy or not, you still need CloudFlare to be the primary nameserver, just creating an `NS` record and pointing that to another nameserver that then points to an `A` record is not possible.

Comment: In response to your comment (now deleted), it's not possible to "chain" nameservers, they should contain the same DNS records. You can add _secondary nameservers_ which would provide backups for the primary (CloudFlare), but again would contain the same records.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this was a serious misconception of mine! (I deleted my last comment since the answer was already clear from your previous response.) All clear now, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: No problem. You can use a their API to update the IP for the `A` record set in CloudFlare, even dynamically as needed if your host changes the IP for your hosting, see this for how to use it:  https://api.cloudflare.com/